# chat not showing up in collection view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am making an application where a patient can chat with a doctor. I am using `firebase` to store and retrieve the data. But whenever I try to send a chat message, the message is successfully added to firebase but it is not showing up at the bottom of `collectionView`(until I select the messages button from the left menu bar ). I am using jsqmessages and making the project in objective-c.

When pressed send button

```
    - (void)didPressSendButton:(UIButton *)button
       withMessageText:(NSString *)text
              senderId:(NSString *)senderId
     senderDisplayName:(NSString *)senderDisplayName
                  date:(NSDate *)date
{
/***  Sending a message. Your implementation of this method should do *at least* the following:
 *
 *  1. Play sound (optional)
 *  2. Add new id<JSQMessageData> object to your data source
 *  3. Call `finishSendingMessage`
 */

if (![_connection isInternet]) {
    [self noInternetView:@"You can not send messages while you are offline"];
    return;
}

[JSQSystemSoundPlayer jsq_playMessageSentSound];

JSQMessage *message = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:senderId
                                         senderDisplayName:senderDisplayName
                                                      date:date
                                                      text:text];

//senderDisplayName = @"You";
[self.messages addObject:message];
[self finishSendingMessage];
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSString *dateString=[formatter1 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"DATE : %@",dateString);
if(_connection.isInternet)
{
[firebaseMethods saveMessageInfoToFirebase:text date:dateString time:timeString msgFrom:senderId msgTo:@"webAdmin"];
[CoreDataMethods saveNewMessageInfoToCoreData:text msgTo:@"webAdmin" msgFrom:senderId date:dateString time:timeString];
}
else
{
    [self showNoInternetMessage];
}
}
```

Please tell me what are the important factors for jsqmessage to work. How do I make `Automatically scroll to bottom` and `display send message right away in collection view` work?

Please ask if you need any extra info in the comments thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After adding message to `self.messages Array ( [self.messages addObject:message];)`

Add he following two lines:

```
[self finishSendingMessageAnimated:YES];
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```